# How can I replace nans in Keras tensor with different value (I have a tensorflow implementation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am writing a custom loss function which calculates mean squared error while ignoring nans. The issue is that my data is an image which occasionally has NaN pixels. I simply want to ignore these nan pixels and calculate the summed squared error between prediction and data, then calculate mean over examples. If I were to write a function for this in Tensorflow I would write:

```
def nanmean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    residuals = y_true - y_pred
    residuals_no_nan = tf.where(tf.is_nan(residuals), tf.zeros_like(residuals), residuals)
    sum_residuals = tf.reduce_sum(residuals_no_nan, [1, 2])

    return sum_residuals
```

But this code does not work as a custom Keras loss function.

I believe I can use keras.backend.switch/zeros_like/sum instead of the tensorflow versions. But I cannot find any replacement for tf.is_nan. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it doesn't work because you are not taking absolute or square values.

If you mean "squared" error, there must be a square in your code (or you will have negative errors and everything will blow to huge negative errors).

```
def nanmean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    residuals = K.square(y_true - y_pred)
    residuals_no_nan = tf.where(tf.is_nan(residuals), tf.zeros_like(residuals), residuals)
    sum_residuals = tf.reduce_sum(residuals_no_nan, [1, 2])

    return sum_residuals
```

But to be honest, I'd probably try to replace the image nans with a certain value before entering the model. I don't know what kind of problems may appear from having nans all around, considering gradients, all intermediate layers, etc.

Comment: That is an incredibly embarrassing oversight, thanks for pointing it out. However, if I use nanmean_squared_error as my loss function it still returns NaN loss, so it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what could be causing the nans in loss after processing?

If I eliminate the nans in the data, it does start training successfully, so it seems related to those nans. However, I have tested the above algorithm on some synthetic data and it gets rid of all nans, so I'm at a loss

Comment: Never mind I just realized where some of the nans will propegate to. Thank you for catching the missing square